# What is the best practice for setting up new Web+App Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-firebase

I have two properties I would like to track via Google Analytics:
1. A cross-platform web-app - I currently have this connected to Google Analytics new App+Web implementation.
2. A marketing website that drives leads to the web-app - I currently have this connected to a separate property with the traditional Google Analytics implementation.

My question is, is it best practice to connect my marketing website to the same App+Web property as my web-app via a new data stream? or should I keep them separate?

It is my understanding that the App+Web is meant to connect all your platforms in one property, I'm just not clear if this should include a marketing website or not.

I would like to be able to track events between the marketing site and the web app, which is why I'm considering have them both under one property.

Thanks!
-Zach

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this as it will be more convenient for you, you can track it in two different streams. I think it will be more purely about data.
In Google Data Studio reports, you can always combine all the data and conversions that you set up into a single live report. I think [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/mobile) help might help.

I always use different Google Analytics streams for apps and different sites, so it's easier for me to track, and in Google Data Studio I collect all the data from Analytics, call tracking, and user session recording [tools](https://www.pageview.com/) in one unit for comprehensive data analysis